# Get list of user-agents from nginx log

Tags: nginx, log-files, logging, parsing

I have nginx log file, and I want to find out market share for each major version of browsers. I am not interested in minor versions and operating systems. I would like to get something like this:

```
100 IE6
 99 IE7
 20 IE8
200 FF2
300 FF3
```

I know how to get the list of user agents from the file, but I want to aggregate the list to see only the major versions of the browsers. Is there a tool that does it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
awk -F'"' '/GET/ {print $6}' /var/log/nginx-access.log | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

- `awk(1)` - selecting full User-Agent string of GET requests
- `cut(1)` - using first word from it
- `sort(1)` - sorting
- `uniq(1)` - count
- `sort(1)` - sorting by count, reversed

PS. Of course it can be replaced by one `awk`/`sed`/`perl`/`python`/etc script. I just wanted to show how rich unix-way is.

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting. I will try it out immediately. :)

Comment: I am trying to get your code to work. Could you please provide more information about each command? (I will do some research too.)

Comment: you can use `man grep`, `man awk` etc.

Comment: Thanks, will do that. I was not explicit enough. The only thing confusing me so far is `{print $6}`, but I guess it represents the piece of data in a line.

Comment: it's generic awk script. It prints 6th column using `"` as separator

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess my log is not standard, but I just had to change $6 to $8 to get it working.

Answer (score 7):

While the [one liner by SaveTheRbtz](https://serverfault.com/a/89904/127548) does the job, it took several hours to parse my `nginx` access log.

Here is a faster version based on his, which takes less than 1 minute per 100MB of log file (corresponding to about 1 million lines):

```
sed -n 's!.* "GET.* "\([[:alnum:].]\+/*[[:digit:].]*\)[^"]*"$!\1!p' /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -rfg
```

It works with the default access log format of `nginx`, which is the same as the `combined` format of Apache's `httpd` and has the `User-Agent` as the last field, delimited by `"`.

Answer (score 4):

To get user agent

```
sudo awk -F"\"" '{print $6}' /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort | uniq -dc
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a slight variation of the accepted answer, using `fgrep` and `cut`.

```
cat your_file.log | fgrep '"GET ' | cut -d'"' -f6 | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

There is something appealing about using "weaker" commands when it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

[Awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) should do the trick, but will supply far more information. I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, Awstats looks similar to Webalizer. I will try it out.

Comment: Awstats was to complicated to install.

Answer (score 2):

[Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/) can do it.

Example:

```
webalizer -o reports_folder -M 5 log_file
```

- `-o reports_folder` specifies folder where report is generated
- `-M 5` displays only the browser name and the major version number
- `log_file` specifies log file name
- source: ftp://ftp.mrunix.net/pub/webalizer/README

Answer (score 0):

I'd use shell script for that: cat, awk pipe, sort and uniq will do the job

Comment: Thanks. I know how to parse logs. I was looking for a tool that already knows how to do it, so I do not have to write a script.