# Parse requests per OS type apache log

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, awk, parsing, linux

I'm trying to return a sorted list of requests per OS type, parsed from an Apache access_log file (not combined format as I need the user-agent info). Here's an example of the output I'm looking for:

```
250 Windows NT 6.1; WOW64
200 X11; Linux x86_64
```

I've been able to find a partial solution, thanks to [this post.](https://serverfault.com/a/89904/127548) Here's what I've got so far:

```
awk -F'"' '/GET/ {print $6}' access_log.3 | cut -d' ' -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Is it possible to use cut to get the strings I need, or is another method needed?

Comment: Can we see some sample input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'"' '/GET/ {print $6}' access_log.3 | awk -F "[()]" '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Comment: Excellent. This works perfectly. Knew I should have been using another awk there after the first pipe. Thanks @theofpa